# Access Foreign Key count in Django Template

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have two `models`: `Farm` and `Animal` with a `ForeignKey` relation.
Each `Farm` contains `x` animals.

I'm doing a table in the frontend with a `for` loop of each `farm`. How can I show the number of animals in each farm?
models:

```
class Farm(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    square_meter = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    friendly_name = models.CharField(max_length=24, blank=True)

    kml = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path_kml, null=True, blank=True)

class Animal(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Animals"

    farm = models.ForeignKey(Farm, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, default=None)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=24, blank=True)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, default=datetime.now)
    tracking = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    kg = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

template:

```
 {% for farm in farms %}
                    <tr>
                       <th scope="row">{{forloop.counter}}</th>
                       <td>{{farm.friendly_name}}</td>
                       <td>{{farm.square_meter}}</td>
                       <td>{{farm. }}</td> # Here I want animal count
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you did not specify a `related_name` for the farm foreign key of `Animal` you can use the default foreign key manager `<class name>_set`. This manager has a `count` method. So

```
{{ farm.animal_set.count }}
```

should provide the count of animals for each farm.

Comment: thx a lot. If i had specified a `related_name` would it be easier to do so?

Comment: Not really. You can specify a related_name you like, but that is not mandatory.